# Creating a new Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

How should I create a new flow?
For example: I have some code

```
viewModelScope.launch(dispatchers.io) {
      method1().collect {
           method2().collect{} 
       }        
}
fun method1(): Flow
fun method2(): Flow
```

From my point of view it is not correct to start the new flow from the `collect` operation, but I cannot substantiate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify: "Creating" a Flow is not the same as "executing/starting" a flow.

You create/build a Flow by utilizing a Flow Builder. Since your two methods return Flows, this is the place where you build them.

Some examples of flow builders are:

- `flowOf()`: to create flow from a given set of items.
- `asFlow()`: extension function to convert collection to flow.
- `flow{}`:
  custom flow builder block to implement any custom
  business logic to create flows by emitting items with `emit()`.

For simple 'static' flow builders like `flowOf(1, 2, 3)`, you can define Flow as properties to reduce overhead, whereas for more complex builder functions with parameters, i.e. when using `flow{}`, methods are the way to go, like in your example.

The Flow is a **cold** stream, which means, your builder code won't get executed before it is collected.

`collect{}` is the correct way of "starting" a Flow's execution. You literally are collecting it's items one by one, executing it's builder code.

Your example has nested `collect{}` calls, which is fine in some cases, but is not best practice in many cases. I recommend reading [Vasya Drobushkov's blog post Nesting vs. Chaining](https://krossovochkin.com/posts/2021_07_08_kotlin_flow_nesting_vs_chaining/) to understand, when to use which approach. In short, chaining means better readability, error handling and testing. The preferred way is to make use of Flow methods `combine()` and `zip()` to chain your operations on multiple flows and using `flatMap{}` operations to apply nesting when needed, with a single collect in the end.

Here's an example:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    flow1.zip(flow2) { intValue, stringValue ->
        "$intValue$stringValue"
    }.collect {
        Log.d(TAG, it)
    }
}

val flow1: Flow = flowOf(1, 2, 3)
val flow2: Flow = flowOf("A", "B", "C")
```

Result:

```
1A
2B
3C
```